# React Native - Android : Host JS Components on remote server

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, remote-server

I am trying to create an android application using react native. In a general scenario, the `MainActivity` invokes the main component from `index.js`. We specify the main component to be registered in this `index.js` by importing any JS component form the file tree. The android application accesses the index file through a local port using `http://localhost:8081/index.js`
For my use-case, I want to host all the JS components on a remote server so that my android application fetches the main component from `index.js` on the remote server every time the app is initialized. This would enable me to make any changes to the functioning of the app on the server itself without having to roll out updates and user needing to download them.

I am still very new to react native and I do not have any code to post since I am still researching. I just have a sample application from which I cannot figure out how the android application knows to read `index.js`. I also cannot figure out how would I configure my application to hit the `index.js` file on my remote server URL.

If anyone knows how to do this or has some documentation references kindly help. I would imagine this is a very general use-case still I cannot find some solid instructions regarding this.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a good use case for Cordova

Answer (score 0):

Use React Native with [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/). Your app will fetch JS bundles and assets over the air. See here: [Configuring OTA in Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-ota-updates/).

> **Instant Updating**:  All Expo apps can be updated in seconds by just clicking Publish in Expo Dev Tools. You don't have to set anything up; it just works this way. If you aren't using Expo, you'd either use *Microsoft Code Push* or roll your *own solution* for this problem. [Source](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/)

...but be aware of the **downsides**: [Why not Expo?](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo/)